# need Help to reshape data on R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I'm looking for a way to reshape this kind of dataset :

```
mydata<-data.frame(var=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=3),code=rep(c("x","y","z"),3),yearA=1:9,yearB=10:18,yearC=20:28)
```

ex:

```
var code    yearA   yearB   yearC
A    x      1       10      20
A    y      2       11      21
A    z      3       12      22
B    x      4       13      23
B    y      5       14      24
B    z      6       15      25
C    x      7       16      26
C    y      8       17      27
C    z      9       18      28
```

to this :

```
code    year    var.A    var.B    var.C
x       yearA    1       4        7
x       yearB    10      13       16
x       yearC    20      23       26
y       yearA    4       5        8
y       yearB    13      14       17
y       yearC    23      24       27
z       yearA    3       6        9
z       yearB    12      15       18
z       yearC    22      25       28
```

I try with melt, and reshape.. but the result is not what I would like. 
Any idea ?

thks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
mydata.melt <- melt(mydata)
mydata.dcast <- dcast(mydata.melt, code+variable~var)
mydata.dcast
```

Answer using reshape2.

Comment: Any idea on whether this task can be done using SQL?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution with Hadley's new **tidyr** (an alternative and partial replacement for **reshape2**) package

```
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")

mydata <- data.frame(var=rep(c("A","B","C"), each=3), 
                     code=rep(c("x","y","z"),3),
                     yearA=1:9, yearB=10:18, yearC=20:28)

mydata %>% 
  gather(year, value, yearA:yearC) %>%
  mutate(var = paste0("var", ".", var)) %>%
  spread(var, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same answer as Jot eN , but with a slight difference to show what `recast` could do.  Keep in mind that one would not normally do `melt();recast()` as the latter encompasses the former.

```
 >mfoo<-melt(mydata)
 >mfoo
   var code variable value
1    A    x    yearA     1
2    A    y    yearA     2
3    A    z    yearA     3
4    B    x    yearA     4
5    B    y    yearA     5
6    B    z    yearA     6
7    C    x    yearA     7
8    C    y    yearA     8
9    C    z    yearA     9
10   A    x    yearB    10
11   A    y    yearB    11
12   A    z    yearB    12
13   B    x    yearB    13
14   B    y    yearB    14
15   B    z    yearB    15
16   C    x    yearB    16
17   C    y    yearB    17
18   C    z    yearB    18
19   A    x    yearC    20
20   A    y    yearC    21
21   A    z    yearC    22
22   B    x    yearC    23
23   B    y    yearC    24
24   B    z    yearC    25
25   C    x    yearC    26
26   C    y    yearC    27
27   C    z    yearC    28
>recast(mfoo,code+variable~var)
Using var, code, variable as id variables
$data
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    4    7
 [2,]   10   13   16
 [3,]   20   23   26
 [4,]    2    5    8
 [5,]   11   14   17
 [6,]   21   24   27
 [7,]    3    6    9
 [8,]   12   15   18
 [9,]   22   25   28

$labels
$labels[[1]]
  code variable
1    x    yearA
2    x    yearB
3    x    yearC
4    y    yearA
5    y    yearB
6    y    yearC
7    z    yearA
8    z    yearB
9    z    yearC

$labels[[2]]
  var
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

So all you'd have to do is `cbind` the first two list elements.
Don't be discouraged:   `melt` and `recast` take some time to get comfortable with.  I invariably have to re-teach myself how to organize the `formula` to get the desired output.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Why not just do `recast(mydata, code  + variable ~ var)`? It also looks like you're using a slightly older version of "reshape2" since newer versions should automatically combine the data and the labels.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  I would have if I'd not been precaffeinated :-) .  I deliberately displayed the output of `melt` in the hopes of providing more clarification to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the clunky `base` R reshape:

```
d <- read.table(text='var code    yearA   yearB   yearC
A    x      1       10      20
A    y      2       11      21
A    z      3       12      22
B    x      4       13      23
B    y      5       14      24
B    z      6       15      25
C    x      7       16      26
C    y      8       17      27
C    z      9       18      28', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


long <- reshape(d, dir='long', varying=list(3:5), idvar=c('code', 'var'), 
                timevar='year', v.names='v', times=c('A', 'B', 'C'))

reshape(long, idvar=c('code', 'year'), timevar='var')

#       code year v.A v.B v.C
# x.A.A    x    A   1   4   7
# y.A.A    y    A   2   5   8
# z.A.A    z    A   3   6   9
# x.A.B    x    B  10  13  16
# y.A.B    y    B  11  14  17
# z.A.B    z    B  12  15  18
# x.A.C    x    C  20  23  26
# y.A.C    y    C  21  24  27
# z.A.C    z    C  22  25  28
```